# Xamarin.Forms handle notification launch (UWP)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Xamarin documentation is a mess all over the internet but I cannot seem to find a solid example of how to handle my Xamarin.Forms application being launched from a notification or handling a notification being clicked while my application is already running.

So I am inside of the `Xamarin.Forms.UWP` application in the `App.xaml.cs` file that handles all the UWP launching. Within the `OnActivated` method I can see that my application receives a fire and gets the proper data from my toast notification. My question is how do I pass that data back into the Xamarin.Forms instance.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
     base.OnActivated(args);
     var _args = (args as LaunchActivatedEventArgs).Arguments;
 }
```

Custom UWP Notification Service:

```
ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
            {
                Launch = "...",
                Visual = new ToastVisual()
                {
                  BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                  {
                      Children =
                        {
                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                Text = title,
                                HintMaxLines = 1
                            },

                            new AdaptiveText()
                            {
                                Text = body
                            }
                        }
                  }
                },
                Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
                {
                    Buttons =
                    {
                        new ToastButton(acceptAction.Key, $"action={acceptAction.Value}")
                        {
                            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Foreground
                        },

                        new ToastButton(declineAction.Key, $"action={declineAction.Value}")
                        {
                            ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var toast = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());

            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

How do I go about sending this _args variable back into the running instance of my cross-platform application so that I can process the logic of navigating to a route, etc.

Furthermore if I have to write some custom code to handle this I will want the code to be easy to integrate the same functionally with the Xamarin.Forms.Android app in this project as well.

Comment: According to your code and description, I guess that you want to send a local toast notification, if yes, you can take a look:[Send a local toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast), you can get the sample at the bottom of page.

Comment: Not even what I want to do. I want to write a cross platform way of responding to the application being launched when a user clicks a notification

Comment: Have you checked this [blog](https://xamarinhelp.com/push-notifications/).